# WooCommerce - Customize shipping address fields

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm customizing the shipping address fields of my WooCommerce site. 
I already change those fields in the order I want. Now I want to change the City field and instead of a text field use a select. 
This new select for city will only show the cities from the state previously selected. Something similar to the way country and state fields work: when I select a country just the states from that country are shown in the State field.
I want to achieve the same but with State and City. Need javascript?

I already search core code but I couldn't find anything.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

`add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'your_function );`

documentation here:
[tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/)